removing WKWebView leaving keyboard stuck open
Updated an app that used UIWebView to use WKWebView instead. However, the keyboard can be made to stay up and remain unresponsive following these steps:

A WKWebView is opened to a URL that has input field(s) and attached to the superview.
Input field is activated and the keyboard is displayed.
Text can be entered with the keyboard as expected.
An action is performed that removes the WKWebView from the superview while the keyboard is displayed. The keyboard is removed as expected along with the WKWebView.
Open a new WKWebView to a URL that has input field(s) and attached to the superview.
Activate an input field and a keyboard is displayed.
An action is performed that removes the WKWebView from the superview while the keyboard is displayed.

At this point, the keyboard will not go away, nor can it be made to go away.
Clearly the desired behavior is for the keyboard to go away every time the webview is made to go away.
I wrote a simple little test app and I can reproduce the issue outside the complexity of the app.
So what is the acceptable method to dispose of a WKWebView? This is a code fragment of what does not work for me, leaving the keyboard lifeless on the second invocation as if it has been detached and forgotten.
    [webView stopLoading];
    webView.navigationDelegate = nil;
    webView.scrollView.delegate = nil;
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
    webView = nil;

Here is a bit more of a working example. I tried to keep it simple and used a double tap to add/remove, but a button or timer works as well to trigger the adding/removing of the webview. I don't think it makes any difference. The issue appears to be disposing of a WKWebView while the keyboard is open and active.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webView = nil;
    webViewIsActive = FALSE;

    tap2Recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    tap2Recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tap2Recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    tap2Recognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap2Recognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}


- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (webViewIsActive) {
        if (keyboardIsVisible) [webView endEditing:true];
        else [self removeWebView];
    } else [self addWebView];
}


- (void)addWebView {
    webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false;
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    webViewIsActive = TRUE;
}

- (void)removeWebView {
    if (webView)
    {
        [webView stopLoading];
        webView.navigationDelegate = nil;
        webView.scrollView.delegate = nil;
        [webView removeFromSuperview];
        webView = nil;
    }

    webViewIsActive = FALSE;
}

Edit: I've explored various bits of tracking the keyboard visibility to no avail for me. I've even gone so far as returning !self.keyboardIsVisible in the gesture delegates but it doesn't seem to make a difference. First time appears to work, second time gives me a keyboard that won't go away.
One strange observation: if I bring up the keyboard, dismiss the keyboard, double tap out to close the webview, then double tap back in and bring up the keyboard, the keyboard is doa. So something gets initialized for the keyboard when it is first revealed and the double tap gesture nukes the keyboard after that.

I tried with a timer, and the keyboard properly dismisses, and while the issue is reproducible with the code from the question, is this the real code from you app? Are you removing the webview based on some gestures?

@Cristik The app does use a double tap to exit. Not my UI design, and this is not the only part of the UI that suffers. I tried with a timer and it failed for me, so if it did not fail for you that gives me something to dig into. Seems like a timer would be just as forceful as somehow digesting the touch events it was looking for?

This looks like a WebKit/UIKit bug, the console is full of warnings related to the Input system, and other autolayout warnings, though the latter ones are unlikely to be the culprit.
But you can work around it if you remove the webview after the keyboard is dismissed.
Add these to viewDidLoad:
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                object:nil
                                                 queue:nil
                                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull notification) {
    self.keyboardIsVisible = YES;
}];

[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                                object:nil
                                                 queue:nil
                                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull notification) {
    self.keyboardIsVisible = NO;
    [self removeWebView];
}];

, and update removeWebView to do its thing only if the keyboardIsVisible flag is off:
- (void)removeWebView {
    if (!self.keyboardIsVisible) {
        [webView stopLoading];
        webView.navigationDelegate = nil;
        webView.scrollView.delegate = nil;
        [webView removeFromSuperview];
        webView = nil;
        webViewIsActive = NO;
    }
}

Also, one more thing, you'll need to [self.view endEditing:YES] instead of [webView endEditing:YES] for this to work:
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (webViewIsActive) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self removeWebView];
    } else {
        [self addWebView];
    }
}

You will also need to handle the situations where the user double taps a second time during the interval the keyboard is being dismissed (which takes around 600ms from what I noticed).

I was elated for a moment. You dispose of the webview when the keyboard is hidden, which makes it hard to actually actually use. If I remove that automatic removal, it all goes bad again. I'll update the question with some random observations, but I may just be sunk. I appreciate your time none the less!

What do you mean by “makes it hard to actually actually use”?

If you bring click in a text field, the keyboard comes up. If you then click off the text field, say to click "sign in" or "search", the keyboard hides and the webview is removed. No sign in or search can be done :-) I do have a 90% solution to this now, except testing has returned they get stuck (user error, but still not ideal). The "solution" was to not use any gesture recognizer, but to actually insert javascript that executes when double tap is recognized in the webview. So no conflicting gesture to foul things up.
